# Pass a javascript array to php in Code Igniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and my js code is in my "view" and I want to pass the value in my controller.

```
var storage =[];

function something()
{

storage.push('the value');

}
```

Now I want a better way to pass the storage array into my PHP. Thanks in advance.
This code is not working because it is in the separate folder.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourPHPFile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data:storage.toString()},
    success: function(result) {
            // handle your success
    },
    error: function() {
      // alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use JSON for this purpose

Comment: Can you elaborate on `"push storage array into my php"`. It's rather broad and vague.

Comment: i know that but i don't know the syntax

Comment: don't mind the push..it's all working..the only problem is passing the array to php file

Comment: How do you want to use it in php? You need to supply more information.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate, the question is too vague. Is the problem in the "passing"? Then the dupe is apt. Or do you already understand that concept, but want a "better" way? In that case, "better" than what?

Comment: i already edit my question..and put that it is created in code igniter..and there is no duplicate question.. you better remove that

Comment: Still not sure what the question is. *"this code is note working because it is in the separate file"* - what does that mean?

Comment: this code is not working because it is in the separate folder..typo error..

Comment: Still not sure what the problem with it being in a separate folder is.

Comment: if your a php developer you should know that.. don't mess with me..

Comment: i need to reopen this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JQuery to post the data

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
             url: "Filename.php",
             data: storage,//no need to call JSON.stringify etc... jQ does this for you
             success: function(resopnse)
             {//check response: it's always good to check server output when developing...
                 }});
```

And in your PHP file

```
$array=json_decode($_POST['jsondata']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to use `jQuery`.

You can do it by sending data to the `server` using `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourPHPFile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data:storage.toString()},
    success: function(result) {
            // handle your success
    },
    error: function() {
      // alert("error");
    }
});
```

On server side, in your `PHP` code do,

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo $data;
```

`$data` will contain `the value`.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON to write in javascript...

```
JSON.stringify(array)
```

and retrieve using...

```
$array=json_decode($_POST['jsondata']);
```